# SVM confusion matrix vs precision/recall scores

Tags: python, svm, confusion-matrix

I have a testset of shape = (1213, 8) and based on this testset, my SVM classifer/model generated the confusion matrix below:

array([[590, 0],

```
   [0, 615]]
```

This confusion matrix means that the classifier is perfect, which I think is impossible because I got a **precision score = 0.72 and a recall score = 0.94.** One would expect both scores to be 100 judging from the confusion matrix!

When I tried another model(Logistic Regression), the confusion matrix looked like:

array([[430, 168],

```
   [187, 428]]
```

with **precision score = 0.72, recall score = 0.70.**

Please, could anyone explain to me why the SVM confusion matrix contradicted the precision/recall scores?

NOTE: I didn't preprocess the data because the model accuracy dropped significantly when standardized. Also, I am using a dataset I collected from a hardware experiment.

Comment: Are you sure you are computing the confusion matrix the correct way for SVM? Sum of data should be 1213, and for the Logistic Regression it matches (430 + 168 + 187 + 428 = 1213), but for the SVM it does not (590 + 615 = 1205). Maybe the complete code could help

Comment: @SilentCloud. I'm been stuck for weeks, sorry I just  figured I did confusion_matrix(y_eval, y_eval) for SVM instead of confusion_matrix(y_eval, y_pred)